# How can I add the next 1st of August as DateTimeField default value in Django?

Tags: django

I have the following model and want to add the next August (midnight time) from now as a default value for `offer_start`:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    """
    A table to store all available offers for an upcoming season
    """
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='offer')
    season_start = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    seasons_duration = models.IntegerField()
    offer_start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, default= ???)
    roi_goal = models.FloatField()
    roi_point = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Offer by {self.club} for season {self.season_start}'
```

Is there any way to make such a specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make a callable with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

def next_august_1():
    today = now().date()
    if (today.month, today.day) >= (8, 1):
        return datetime(today.year+1, 8, 1)
    return datetime(today.year, 8, 1)
```

and then pass the callable to the `DateTimeField`:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    # …
    #                          without parenthesis 🖟
    offer_start = models.DateTimeField(default=next_august_1)
```

Comment: works nicely, thanks! Two questions: Why do I call the function without parenthesis and where would I place such functions/callables in my models.py usually? All at the very top or below/above the associated model?

Comment: @Jonas: usually above the model. You should not call the function, but pass a reference to the function, such that each time when you construct an `Offer`, it will evaluate the function and use the result. This is necessary since otherwise it takes the value when you *started* the server, not when you create the `Offer`.